# Express 4 and custom modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following code in `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
....
var app = express();
var defaultPage = require('./routes/default');
app.use('/default', defaultPage);
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

and inside `default.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/page', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send({
    pageTo:"app.entity", params:{"entityID":1}
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

when I request `/default/page`, I get the `json` response, but the headers are not set (as configured in app.js). If I modify the `default.js` and add following lines, I can see the headers are being set

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

The problem is, very soon I will be having more than 10-15 modules and copying this code in every module, doesn't look valid option. Please let me know why setting header in `app.js` is not working.

**EDIT1:**
Here goes the CURL output with `app.use` in `app.js`

```
D:\node_service>curl --verbose http://localhost:3000/default/page
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1e3cf48
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1e3cf48) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /default/page HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 47
< ETag: W/"2f-1d1f551c"
< Date: Sun, 03 May 2015 13:44:30 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{"pageTo":"app.entity","params":{"entityID":1}}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

And after adding `router.use` in default.js, here is the output

```
D:\node_service>curl --verbose http://localhost:3000/default/page
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1e1cf48
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1e1cf48) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /default/page HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 47
< ETag: W/"2f-1d1f551c"
< Date: Sun, 03 May 2015 13:47:07 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{"pageTo":"app.entity","params":{"entityID":1}}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that your headers `app.use` needs to come first.

Comment: Please check the edits I have done to the question. The code lists the header information, after sending request via curl.

Comment: In your edits you say "Here goes the CURL output with app.use in app.js". Does this mean you tested it with all your middlewares registered before your routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the reason (silly me), I was using the sample project generated by express generator, which had lot of middleware to generate 404 and 500 response (using default jade engine). In my case, I wanted JSON output always. I did following steps and it worked

1. Commented all res.render calls.
2. Registered middleware prior to calling `app.use`.

The code now looks like this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use('/default', defaultPage);
```

Earlier it was in reverse order.